# Editing file in /var/www/html as an ec2 user from VSCode makes ec2 break

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, npm, amazon-ec2, ssh

When I try to edit any file from /var/www/html as an ec2 user from VSCode it makes the ec2 essentially break. Everything starts going super slow, to the point that even sshing back into the instance doesn't work (assuming that it won't connect after 5 minutes).

Here's some extra context.

1. I've run both

```
sudo chown -R username:username /var/www/html/project
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/try
```

2. I am connecting to the ec2 in VSCode using Microsoft Remote SSH and a password. Here is my config file:

```
Host ec2
  HostName ecx-x-xx-xx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
  IdentityFile C:/cygwin64/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa
  User username
```

When I ssh in, I click the .. until I reach /var/www/html/project and then I try editing files in there, which causes it to "break." However, when I edit them through sshing in cygwin (with just nano file.jsx), it doesn't cause any issues. I want to get my VSCode editing properly working though.

Thanks for any help or feedback.

Comment: What instance type is this?  What does the CPU credit balance look like during this?

Comment: @AnonCoward It's an amazon-linux-2 ec2 instance. However, I'm not sure how to check CPU credit balance. I'm only trying to save one file though, so it shouldn't be taking too much CPU.

Comment: Click on the instance in the EC2 management console so that it displays Instance Details. Take a look at **Instance type** and let us know what it says. Then, click the **Monitoring** tab and look at **CPU Utilization** -- you can change the time period by   by clicking a time range above the charts (eg 1h, 3h, 12h, 1d). You will also find **CPU Credit** charts there.

Comment: What instance type, not operating system.  Something like t2.micro.  If it's small enough, and starved for CPU credits, then the node server VS code uses might be pushing you over the edge.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It's a t2.micro instance and the CPU Utilization hasn't spiked since I've joined on VSCode

Comment: Next suggestion: SSH into the instance and run `top` -- this will show CPU utilization for processes running on the instance (assuming it is running Linux). Then, do your VSCode stuff and see what `top` shows.

Comment: Could it be that you're being bitten by [this](https://medium.com/good-robot/use-visual-studio-code-remote-ssh-sftp-without-crashing-your-server-a1dc2ef0936d)?